# Gold - What is GB01/CHF? How does a metal account work?

Tags: gold, switzerland, precious-metals, metals

I opened a metal account (in German they call it *Metallkonto*, I hope to translation is correct). In the Web interface of the bank I see almost no info (no price, no profit or loss in percent).

The only thing I see:

- Your purchase GB01/CHF 51.924600
- You own 172.00 GB01

So what does this little info mean? What is `GB01` exactly? How does a metal account work? What do I need to check?

What exactly is the point of a metal account? Who is this product aimed at?
What I need to know as a owner of `GB01`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GB01 means a [gold bar with 1g](https://www.bcf.ch/de/fkb-digital/digitale-dienstleistungen/rechner-und-tools/edelmetalle) and GB01/CHF means the price in swiss francs, in this case 51.92 CHF per gramm.
And to add the important investment advice: if you can't figure out what you are trading, keep your fingers off.